# Why is it necessary to prevent Skynet from killing young John Connor?

Tags: terminator-series, terminator-genisys, terminator-dark-fate

We see in *Terminator: Dark Fate* that John is killed in the 1990s, some years after the events of *Judgment Day*. So if it has been done, who is the John in *Terminator: Rise of the Machines*, *Salvation* and *Genisys*?

If the death of the past John has no impact on future John and his Resistance, then why is it **necessary** to prevent Skynet from going to the past and kill him?

Why does Skynet itself send their machines to kill young John if they know it has no effect on the future John?

And also, the prevention of Skynet's creation in the past had no effect on the future Skynet at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of *Terminator: Dark Fate* as *Terminator 3: Redux*—it completely ignores all the Terminators after *Terminator 2*. The producers explained it by saying those movies took place in an alternative universe.

The rights to the Terminator franchise reverted back to James Cameron around 2018, and he didn’t want hemmed in by anything anyone had done since *T2* so he ignored *T3*, *Salvation*, and *Genisys*.

Comment: So in other words, Cameron has confirmed branching timelines in the Terminator universe? :)

Comment: ...or at the very least, retconned timelines ;-)